# JFrog Artifactory for .Net WebApplications

Tags: c#, asp.net, artifactory

I was having a look at the repository types provided by JFrog and I have come across nuget repository.

But I failed to find a way to maintain the WebApplications of .Net. If I am not wrong, everything in .Net is not of just nuget type.

To put it straight how to do I maintain published websites in JFrog Artifactory? Is that even possible?

If yes, How? 
If no, how to maintain versioning for the .Net Artifacts?

P.S. - Is Generic repo type the only way?

Comment: We're running into the same issue. We are thinking of using a Maven repository, but it doesn't seem like a good solution. Please let us know what you have come up with.

Comment: We haven't found any repository of such kind. We are using generic repository for now and zipping the dotnet artifcats